# Sink Supply Line

Tags: water, faucet

I have a new sink in my laundry room that has cold and hot water supply lines going to it. I have verified that both of the shutoff valves are working correctly and water is coming out when they are turned on. But when the supply lines are hooked to the faucet only the hot is working. I've tried 2 different supply lines and 2 different faucets and get the same behavior. I'm at a loss as to what the issue might be. Any recommendations on things to try?

Comment: Same brand/model faucet on each try?

Comment: With nothing connected to the cold supply, opening the shutoff water comes out?  With the supply line connected to the shutoff, turning on the shutoff water comes out? With supply line connected to faucet, and shutoff turned on, turning on faucet no water comes out?

Comment: Do the instructions for the faucet mention adjusting anything (mixer, thermostatic valve, etc.)?

Comment: Different models of faucet used. Water comes out of the valve and out of the supply line when connected to the value with it turned on. Can honestly say I didn't read the directions for the faucet, this is usually 'falling off a log' easy. I'm just baffled as to what the problem is. I think taking the faucet off completely and taking a look at it is about the only thing I can think of left to try.

Comment: When you're testing the faucet, are both supply lines connected (hot and cold), and both shutoff valves open?

Comment: What's the make and model of the faucets you've tried?

Comment: Yes, everything is open as it should be. One of the faucets was a Moen, the other a Delta, models I have no idea. While I'm not a master plumber, I'm pretty decent at it, and have replaced about every faucet in our house at one time or another...but this one has me stumped. Thanks for the replies guys...I just would hate to call a plumber to look at it and discover it's something really obvious and stupid. :)

Comment: Seems unlikely that you got two defective faucets, from two separate manufacturers.  Without being able to see what you've done, it's not possible for us to notice if you've made any mistakes.  Maybe posting some photos might help?

Comment: Assuming that you have lines, flexible or rigid, between the shut-off valves and the faucet... have you replaced these lines? Just trying to confirm that you have water all the way up to the faucet. You only mention that there is water at the shut-off valves. I'm guessing that one of the lines is faulty.

Comment: I just did another test on it quick and switched the the cold water supply to the hot faucet and hot water supply to the cold faucet and the hot side now does not work and the cold does....so that rules out the faucet being the issue. So, it's something with the cold water supply valve/supply line.

Answer (score 1):

According to your tests, the supply line is certainly the culprit. Are these new replacements? If not, do replace them with new. If so, then one is faulty. Either way, sounds like the answer is the line between the valve and the faucet.

Comment: I have seen "safe" supply lines that will shut off internally if the pressure drop exceeds some preset value.http://www.wattscanada.ca/pages/whatsnew/floodsafe_connectors.asp

Comment: Yes, the Floodsafe supply lines have been around for a while. They have been know to be faulty as well, triggering the emergency valve incorrectly.

Comment: @Dan can you confirm if the supply lines you're using have the feature mentioned by DJohnM?

Comment: Well, after trying everything else, I replaced the brand new shark bite valve with another new one and that fixed it. Thanks all for the comments.